# Rendering images dynamically into DOM. Glitchy effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to dynamically render a set of questions and an image (positioned next to each other) each time a button is clicked.

I'm using bootstrap and here is my code.

```
    <div v-if="!submittedAnswer" class="row text-center" id="questions-container">
        <div class="image-holder col-sm-5">
            <img :src="questions[questionIndex].imgUrl" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
            <div v-for="(item,index) in questions[questionIndex].choices" class="col-sm-7 text-center choice">
                <p class="shadow-effect
                " :class="{'active': activeChoiceId == index}" :id="index" @click="chooseAnswer">{{item}}</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

As can be seen both the image and the question set are rendered in their own respective columns. The issue im facing is that they load in a weird order which in turn creates a glitchy looking affect. I've managed to screenshot what happens.

[image]

Even though they are split in two separate columns. The second column seems to partially render in the area of the first column. Then when the image renders, it pushes them over, creating a buggy looking effect.

I've tried creating larger space between them with margins, padding. Or using flexbox instead but the issue still persists.

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap 3, and your question is related to layout, it should contain the [tag:twitter-bootstrap] tag.

Answer (score 0):

When your view renders, it renders like this:

```
<div class="image-holder col-sm-5">{{ image }}</div>
<div class="col-sm-7 text-center choice"">{{ answer }}</div>
<div class="col-sm-7 text-center choice"">{{ answer }}</div>
<div class="col-sm-7 text-center choice"">{{ answer }}</div>
.
.
.
```

Since the bootstrap grid has 12 spaces, the "col-sm-7" div blocks after the first one are rendered in a new line, because they have no more space to render.

What you need to do is to wrap all the answers inside a `<div class="col-sm-7">` block, so they would render correctly. Something like this:

```
<div v-if="!submittedAnswer" class="row text-center" id="questions-container">
    <div class="image-holder col-sm-5">
        <img :src="questions[questionIndex].imgUrl" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div v-for="(item,index) in questions[questionIndex].choices" class="text-center choice">
            <p class="shadow-effect
            " :class="{'active': activeChoiceId == index}" :id="index" @click="chooseAnswer">{{item}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```